# Test to verify that a Linq statement was executed when returns a array of integers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, unit-testing, testing

***I want to verify a method was executed but this one use a linq statement and returns an array of integers and I have the next error***:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: m => m.Remove(right, 0)
> Non-overridable members (here: SortingAlgorithms.Remove) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

This is the methos that I'm testing:

```
 public int[] Merge(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        int[] result = new int[left.Length + right.Length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (left.Length != 0 || right.Length != 0)
        {
            if (left.Length > 0 && left[i] <= right[j])
            {
                result[k] = left[i];
                left = Remove(left, i);
                ++k;
            }
            else
            {
                result[k] = right[j];
                right = Remove(right, j);
                ++k;
            }
            if (left.Length == 0)
            {
                while (right.Length != 0)
                {
                    result[k] = right[j];
                    right = Remove(right, j);
                    ++k;
                }
            }
            if (right.Length == 0)
            {
                while (left.Length != 0)
                {
                    result[k] = left[i];
                    left = Remove(left, i);
                    ++k;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the remove method:

```
 public int[] Remove(int[] array, int i)
    {
        return array.Where(x => x != array.ElementAt(i)).ToArray();
    }
```

This is my test:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Merge_CheckRemoveIsCalled()
    {
        int[] array = { -2, 80, };
        var mock = new Mock<SortingAlgorithms>();
        var mockLinq = new Mock<IQueryable>();

        int[] left = { 80 };
        int[] right = { -2 };

        mock.Setup(m => m.Remove(right, 0)).Returns(array);

        shorting.Merge(left, right);

        mock.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<int[]>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
    }
```

**How could I mock this remove method?**

Comment: The better question is *why* would you need to mock that method. You appear to be mocking a concrete class, which is not meaningful. What you ought to be testing is whether the `Merge` method works correctly (given a particular input, result in merged output), not whether it does so by calling some specific, concrete, unmockable `Remove` method some time -- that proves (almost) nothing. That said, if you think otherwise, making `Remove` `virtual` should be enough to allow a mock.

Comment: Thanks for answering and you are right I was doing this test although it does not make much sense but placing virtual worked